# Is there a wild card that can be used for any column?

Tags: powershell

If I already have a variable `$test` with a set of users. 
Each user entry has 10 columns that represent email addresses.
How to return only values with a specific entries from the `$test` variable.

Example of a user entry:

```
Alias             : User01
EmailAddresses_1  : X500:/o=bla bla bla b
EmailAddresses_2  : x500:/o=bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1
EmailAddresses_3  : smtp:USR1@testdomain1.com
EmailAddresses_4  : smtp:user01@testdomain1.com
EmailAddresses_5  : smtp:user1@testdomain2.com
EmailAddresses_6  : SMTP:user001@testdomain1.com
EmailAddresses_7  : SIP:usr01@testdomain1.com
EmailAddresses_8  : smtp:u1@testdomain2.com
EmailAddresses_9  :
EmailAddresses_10 :
```

So as you can see, some columns are populated with different values and other are empty.
How can I return only the columns with a specific value assuming I only have the variable to work with.

For example all the user entries with only the values that start with "SIP:*"

A little guiding light is appreciated.

Comment: Is $test an array? Or is it a single entry of the example you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the `Alias` of all the users that have a property name that starts with `EmailAddresses` and contains a specific value, this might help you out:

```
$Test = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Alias             = 'User01'
    EmailAddresses_1  = 'X500:/o=bla bla bla b'
    EmailAddresses_2  = 'x500:/o=bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1'
    EmailAddresses_3  = 'smtp:USR1@testdomain1.com'
    EmailAddresses_4  = 'smtp:user01@testdomain1.com'
    EmailAddresses_5  = 'smtp:user1@testdomain2.com'
    EmailAddresses_6  = 'SMTP:user001@testdomain1.com'
    EmailAddresses_7  = 'SIP:usr01@testdomain1.com'
    EmailAddresses_8  = 'smtp:u1@testdomain2.com'
    EmailAddresses_9  = $null
    EmailAddresses_10 = $null
}

$SearchString = 'SIP:'

$Found = Foreach ($T in $Test) {
    $Properties = $Test | Get-Member | Where {($_.MemberType -EQ 'NoteProperty') -and ($_.Name -like 'EmailAddresses*')}
    Foreach ($P in $Properties) {
        if ($T.($P.Name) -like "$SearchString*") {
            $T.Alias
        }
    }
}

$Found | Select -Unique
```

After clarification in the comments, this might be more what you're looking for:

```
$SearchString = 'SIP:'
$Test | Select Alias, 
@{Name='EmailAddres1';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_1 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_1}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres2';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_2 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_2}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres3';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_3 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_3}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres4';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_4 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_4}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres5';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_5 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_5}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres6';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_6 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_6}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres7';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_7 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_7}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres8';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_8 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_8}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres9';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_9 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_9}}},
@{Name='EmailAddres10';Expression={if ($_.EmailAddresses_10 -like "$SearchString*"){$_.EmailAddresses_10}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for a prompt response, it does not address my issue, but that is probably because I explained the situation at hand in a wrong manner. What I am hoping to find is a way to retrieve all objects but filtering away certain values. Or list only certain values, but all aliases are inclusive, isolating values with x500 addresses or getting only those emailaddresses with a certain suffix.

Comment: Answer updated, I hope this is now what you're looking for. If it's still not ok, please clarify your question further with an example of expected input and output.

Comment: I can confirm that it retrieves the desired result, the fact of using the expression in the filtering did not evade me, I have however hoped that there might be a way that was unfamiliar to me that could loop through all columns without specifying the column name. If each object had hundreds of columns this method would become a nightmare. Is there a wild card representation of all columns? is what I am looking for at all possible? and last but not least, I am impressed at your answer rate, your assistance is among the best I have experienced so far. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you out :) With regards to your other questions, I'm afraid there's not something more general you could do, because you need to name the property name of the object. Unless you do something as indicated in my first answer, looping through the property names.